# regex_replace replaces only one occurrence for some reason

Tags: c++, regex

With regex, I perform

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string parsed = regex_replace(
        "import core\nimport io\n",
        (regex) "(^|\r|\n|\r\n)(\\s*)import\\s(.*)\n",
        "#include \"$3.h++\"\n");
    cout << parsed << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
#include "core.h++"
#include "io.h++"
```

but it actually was:

```
#include "core.h++"
import io
```

Where did I go wrong? Why does it only replace one occurance? Is my regex bad?

I've tried changing the match_flag_options from regex_constants, but to no avail

Comment: The same thing, but with `regex_replace("hello world\n    hello nerd", (regex) "(^|\r|\n|\r\n)(\\s*)([^\#].*[^\;\.\{\}])\n", "$1$2$3\;\n")` does actually replace both occurances

Comment: Your regex requires the pattern to include a `\n` at the end. Your input string does not have such a thing at the end of the second line.

Comment: That's a fair point, but even with the \n at the end (which I've now edited in), it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Does an example with replacing `"aa"` via `"a"` to `"b"` yield `"bb"` or `"ba"`?

Comment: You need to specify [`std::regex_constants::multiline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type#Constants) as one of the regex traits.

Comment: It yields "bb".

Comment: @G.M. regex_replace takes regex_constants::match_flag_type as an optional parameter. I can't supply multiline, so rather than just `^`, I'm resorting to `(^|\r|\n|\r\n)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  You need to specify the multiline requirement in the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is somewhat needlessly complicated, it could just be

```
regex(R"(^\s*import\s+([^\s]+)\s*$)", std::regex_constants::multiline)
```

Note that we need to pass in `std::regex_constants::multiline` as a constructor parameter so that `^/$` match the start/end of lines rather than the start/end of the entire input.

(Some changes I've made to your regex:

- match multiple spaces between import and the word after
- allow spaces after the 'import' word (and disallow them within that word)
- no need to match end of line characters (no need to include them in the substitution either!)
- Use the [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) syntax so we don't need to double escape everything
  )